# How to restart agetty?

Tags: systemd, agetty

I'm trying to restart services after a `yum update` on RHEL 7.4. I could restart pretty much everything, but fail to see how to do this for *agetty*:

```
# needs-restarting
736 : /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
```

Systemctl does not recognize `agetty` as a service.

As far as I can see agetty is part of the system and has to do with opening the login prompt.

Can I restart it without rebooting the server, and how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Traditionally, you restart `getty` implementations by killing them — whatever spawned them then takes care of restarting them.

With systemd, you can do this “properly” by restarting `getty@tty...`:

```
sudo systemctl restart getty@tty1
```

Comment: Cannot figure out analogical syntax for restarting this process: "/sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220" - any suggestion please?

Comment: @Boris it depends how you started it... I would guess `sudo systemctl restart getty@ttyS0`, but if that doesn’t work, I don’t know; you should ask a separate question.